# NSUserDefaults returns null after registerUserDefaults worked previously

Tags: ios, testing, nsuserdefaults

My code worked before, now it doesn't for some reason. I was testing on device, then I removed the app and tested with `Test Flight`. Now the defaults fail to register.

```
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:50]: @"DidBuyInAppPurchase",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]: @"AdShow"
                    };
NSLog(@"appDefaults %@", appDefaults);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSLog(@"user default ad show %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AdShow"]);
```

Logs show

> appDefaults {
>       0 = AdShow;
>       50 = DidBuyInAppPurchase;
>   }

so that dictionary is being created just fine. And then logging the key:

> user default ad show (null)

Comment: have you check edited answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You used `NSNumber numberWithInt` so you need to retrive int with using

```
[NSUserDefaults integerForKey]
```

Like,

```
NSLog(@"user default ad show %ld", (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AdShow"]);
```

**Edit 1 :-**  You can store and retrieve it with 3 option,

**Option 1 :-** If you want to save **int** with **Objectforkey** with register class in **Nsuserdefault** then use below format,

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"50",@"DidBuyInAppPurchase",@"0",@"AdShow", nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DidBuyInAppPurchase"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AdShow"]);
```

Output Image:-

[image]

**Option 2 :-** Store whole dictionary in NSUserDefaults and retrieve it in Dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:50],@"DidBuyInAppPurchase",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"adshow", nil];
NSLog(@"appDefaults %@", dic);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"appdeaults"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSLog(@"user default ad show %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"appdeaults"]);
```

Retrieve it in Dictionary

```
 NSMutableDictionary *mutableRetrievedDictionary = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"appdeaults"] mutableCopy];

 NSLog(@"==Dict %@",mutableRetrievedDictionary);
```

**Option 3 :-** Last and Easy store int for with Individual key.

```
 // Store number with separate key
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"saveint10"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15] forKey:@"saveint15"];

   //Retrieve it like ,
    NSInteger int1 = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveint10"] intValue];
    NSInteger int2 = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveint15"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"==int1 is %ld",(long)int1);
    NSLog(@"==int2 is %ld",(long)int2);
```

I hope this info is useful for you.

Comment: But then it's not registered, it' just resets it every time. Using `integerForKey` returns 0 every time.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs check edited answer from edit 1 , you have 3 option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value individually:

```
NSUserDefaults *kUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[kUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:50] forKey:@"DidBuyInAppPurchase"];
[kUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"AdShow"];
[kUserDefaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"User default ad show = %@", [kUserDefaults objectForKey:@"AdShow"]);
```